# Why won't this allow me to get document field values?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this rule in my Firestore

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /user/{userEmail} {
    allow create: if request.auth && request.auth.email == userEmail;
  }
  match /user/{userEmail=**}/{field} {
    allow get: if field == 'username';
  }
}
```

I just want to allow `get` using `where` from anyone if `field` of any document is `username`, but I think I'm doing all this wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the app code that performs the query you are working with, along with the data in your database that matches it.  It will be much more clear than the description you have now.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Doug that your question is very much lacking in detail, one detail does stand out:

```
  match /user/{userEmail=**}/{field} {
    allow get: if field == 'username';
  }
```

matches are done solely on collection and document paths - NOT FIELDS.

Also, SECURITY RULES ARE NOT FILTERS.  They *will not*, by themselves, allow you get only some documents and not others - your *queries* do that, and they must match the security rules you have specified.

Please read the Security Rules documentation carefully.